# How does scikit-learn perform $\chi^2$ feature selection on non-categorical features?

Tags: svm, feature-selection, text-mining

I'm experimenting with $\chi^2$ feature selection for some text classification tasks. I understand that $\chi^2$ test checks the dependencies B/T two categorical variables, so if we perform $\chi^2$ feature selection for a binary text classification problem with binary BOW vector representation, each $\chi^2$ test on each (feature, class) pair would be a very straightforward $\chi^2$ test with 1 degree of freedom.

Quoting from the documentation: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html#sklearn.feature_selection.chi2,

> This score can be used to select the n_features features with the
>   highest values for the χ² (chi-square) statistic from X, which must
>   contain booleans or frequencies (e.g., term counts in document
>   classification), relative to the classes.

It seems to me that we we can also perform $\chi^2$ feature selection on DF (word counts) vector presentation.

**My 1st question is:** How does sklearn discretize the integer-valued feature into categorical?

My second question is similar to the first. From the demo codes here: http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/dev/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html

It seems to me that we can also perform $\chi^2$ feature selection on a TF*IDF vector representation.

**My 2nd question is:** How does sklearn perform $\chi^2$ feature selection on real-valued features?

Comment: I have no experience with scikit-learn, hence just a hint on the base of rapidminer-experience: 1. Integer values can be treated as categorical or real-valued. 2. Chi2-Feature-Selection on real-valued features most likely requires a discretization beforehand, hence if the integer is treated as real-valued, a discretization is also performed here. I suggest to look into the source code.

Comment: Thank you @steffen for your suggestion. This has been answered by one of the developers of sklearn here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573030/perform-chi-2-feature-selection-on-tf-and-tfidf-vectors. It becomes quite clear if one thinks of the NULL hypothesis as "document class has no influence over feature frequency".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573030/perform-chi-2-feature-selection-on-tf-and-tfidf-vectors

Think of the NULL hypothesis as "document class has no influence over feature frequency".